# How do I take the limit of this trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I was wondering how I could take this limit:

$\lim_{a→1}\frac{\sin(a^4 - 1)}{a^3-1}$

My idea was that if I can get the denominator and the inside of the sin to be the same I can use the sandwich theorem or maybe cancel out the a-1 in the denominator somehow.  To go about this I did the following operations:

$$\lim_{a\to 1}\frac{\sin(a^4 - 1)}{(a-1)(a^2+a+1)}$$

$$\lim_{a\to 1}\frac{\sin(a^4 - 1) * (a + 1)(a^2 + 1)}{(a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)*(a^2+a+1)}$$

$$\lim_{a\to 1}\frac{\sin(a^4 - 1) * (a + 1)(a^2 + 1)}{(a^4 - 1)*(a^2+a+1)}$$

$$\lim_{a\to 1}\frac{\sin(a^4 - 1)}{(a^4 - 1)} *\lim_{a\to 1}\frac{(a^2 + 1)(a + 1)}{(a^2 + a + 1)}$$

At this step I tried to use the sandwich theorem to find $\lim_{a\to 1}\frac{\sin(a^4 - 1)}{(a^4 - 1)}$

However I got $(-\infty,\infty)$ Like so:

$$\lim_{a\to 1} -1 < \sin(a^4-1) < 1$$

$$\lim_{a\to 1} \frac{-1}{a^4 - 1} < \frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^4-1} < \frac{1}{a^4 - 1}$$

$$= -\infty < \frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^4-1} < \infty$$

So I'm at a loss as to what I can do from here on.  Or is what I've done just completely wrong?

Comment: Use that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin{(x)}}x=1$ where $x=a^4-1$

Comment: I think I understand so if I say that ${a^4 - 1 = x}$ then a x -> 0 so then I end up with the classic $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$  Which then turns into 1 resulting in the answer being the limit of the second part

Answer (score 2):

You can just note that
$$
\lim_{a\to 1} \frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^3-1} = \lim_{a \to 1}\frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^4-1} \cdot \frac{a^4-1}{a^3-1}=\lim_{a\to 1} \frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^4-1} \cdot \lim_{a \to 1} \frac{a^4-1}{a^3-1}=1 \times \frac 43= \frac 43
$$

Comment: Ah mon ami Pierre m’a marché dessus la langue!

Comment: That's what I'm wondering right now as well

Comment: You can just Use Ruffini's rule to factor $(a-1)$ in both the numerator and the denominator.
$$\lim_{a \to 1} \frac{a^4-1}{a^3-1} = \lim_{a \to 1} \frac{(a-1)(a^3+a^2+a+1)}{(a-1)(a^2+a+1)}$$

Comment: Oh I feel stupid.  I've spent the last 20 minutes factoring ${sin(a^4−1)}$ as  ${(a-1)(a+1)(a^2 - 1)}$ and wondering how you got your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sexy trick:

$$\frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^3-1}=\frac{\sin(a^4-1)}{a^4-1}\times\frac{a^4-1}{a^3-1}$$